# Getting missing expression error code in SQL when trying to create a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an error

> ORA-00936: missing expression

and can't figure out why.

I'm trying to create a table and add some values to it

```
create table flight
(
    flightId int, 
    departure VARCHAR2(15), 
    destination VARCHAR2(15), 
    dateOfFlight int, 
    timeOfFlight int
);

insert into flight (flightId, departure, destination, dateOfFlight, timeOfFlight) 
values ('SA123', 'Zurich', 'Bonn', (to_date('12/Jan/09','dd/mm/yyyy')),, '6:45');

insert into flight (flightId, departure, destination, dateOfFlight, timeOfFlight) 
values ('BA123', 'London', 'NewYork', (to_date('21/Jan/09','dd/mm/yyyy')),, '6:30');

insert into flight (flightId, departure, destination, dateOfFlight, timeOfFlight) 
values ('BA555', 'London', 'Dublin', (to_date('23/Jan/09','dd/mm/yyyy')),, '14:45');

insert into flight (flightId, departure, destination, dateOfFlight, timeOfFlight) 
values ('FA345', 'Paris', 'Zurich', (to_date('21/Jan/09','dd/mm/yyyy')),, '16:30');

select * from flight
```

Comment: Is it the extra '('?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have both a `)` and a `,` too much at the end. It will work if you remove them.

You are also using the wrong datatypes some places, for example you are tring to set flightid to some value that is not an integer.

*Please check as correct answer if you find it working.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you **look at what you wrote**?

- obviously, two consecutive commas (as you were already told), but that's the least of your problems
- if `flightid` is `integer`, how do you plan to put `SA123` into it?
- similarly, if `dateofflight` is `integer`, why did you try to insert `date` (suspicious, though) (`to_date('12/Jan/09','dd/mm/yyyy')`) into it?

  - Why suspicious? Because format model doesn't match value you're inserting. `12/Jan/09` is `dd/Mon/yy`, not `dd/mm/yyyy`.
  - Besides, be careful! Working with months' names (instead of numbers) can be tricky. For example, your `Jan` can't be used in my database as `Jan` is - I presume - English, while my database speaks Croatian. Safer option is to use `01` for January; or, provide additional parameter to `to_date` - `nls_date_language`
- the same goes for the last column, `timeofflight` which you declared as `integer` and wanted to insert `6:45` into it
- in Oracle, you shouldn't separate date and time. Use a single column whose datatype is `DATE`

When fixed, your code should look like this:

```
SQL> create table flight
  2  (
  3      flightid     varchar2(10),
  4      departure    varchar2(15),
  5      destination  varchar2(15),
  6      dateofflight date
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into flight (flightid, departure, destination, dateofflight)
  2  values ('SA123', 'Zurich', 'Bonn', to_date('12/01/2009 06:45','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into flight (flightid, departure, destination, dateofflight)
  2  values ('BA123', 'London', 'NewYork', to_date('21/01/2009 06:30','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from flight;

FLIGHTID   DEPARTURE       DESTINATION     DATEOFFLIGHT
---------- --------------- --------------- ----------------
SA123      Zurich          Bonn            12/01/2009 06:45
BA123      London          NewYork         21/01/2009 06:30

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to enter 6 values and you only have 5 in the insert or you have an extra comma :)